# Xhtml write URL,which one is correct?

Tags: javascript, xhtml-1.0-strict

I need to write a url within a javascript, but do not know if I should write & for & symbol.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<![CDATA[
 var link = 'http://example.com/query?id=1' . '&ref=' . document.referrer;
 ]]></script>
```

Or

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<![CDATA[
 var link = 'http://example.com/query?id=1' . '&amp;ref=' . document.referrer;
 ]]></script>
```

Answer (score 4):

Inside `CDATA`, there's no need to escape `&` and it should not be escaped in the resulting URL, so the first one is correct.

Comment: Almost. You still need to [encode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) the `document.referrer`.

Comment: If you took the CDATA markers away, then the second example would be correct (except for the encoding again) but not HTML compatible.

Comment: @Quentin: that's true. I was focusing on the difference between the two code pieces.

Comment: Oh, and `.` is not a concatenation operator in JavaScript. They need changing to `+`

Comment: @Joachim — indeed, that's why I'm making comments instead of trying to write a better answer, these are side issues. :)

Answer (score 2):

Correct would be

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<![CDATA[
 var link = 'http://example.com/query?id=1' + '&ref=' + encodeURIComponent(document.referrer);
]]></script>
```

You must not XML-escape characters in CDATA sections. That's the whole *point* of using them in the first place.

But note the URL-encoding that you forgot. And JavaScript string concatenation works with `+`, not `.`.